# Qt5, CMake, AUTOMOC and precompiled headers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake, qt5, stdafx.h

How to specify a precompiled header to the output of CMake (2.8.12.1) AUTOMOC ?

So far, in the CMakeLists.txt I've tried these two separately:

```
 set(AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS "-bstdafx.h")
 set(AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS "-fstdafx.h")
```

The generated AUTOMOC output when building the project (project_automoc.cpp) only contains the moc_xxx.cpp files:

```
/* This file is autogenerated, do not edit*/
/// <- stdafx.h should be here ?!?!
#include "moc_widget_fps.cpp"
#include "moc_widget_sysevents.cpp"
```

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I decided to just turn the AUTOMOC feature off for projects that use precompiled headers:

```
set_target_properties (ProjectName PROPERTIES AUTOMOC FALSE)

# Set the headers that need moc'ing
file (GLOB MOC_FILES widget_filetransfer.h widget_main_menu.h widget_main_toolbar.h)
QT5_WRAP_CPP (MOC_SOURCES ${MOC_FILES})

...
# Force PCH for the generated MOC files
foreach (src_file ${MOC_SOURCES})
    set_source_files_properties (${src_file} 
  PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yustdafx.h /FIstdafx.h"
)
endforeach()
```

Comment: When turning automoc off, note that on Windows you can get the list of all header files with the Q_OBJECT macro easily by executing `findstr /m /s "Q_OBJECT" "*.h"` on the source folder from the command line. There surely is a similar command for Linux/MacOS

Comment: is there any other solution to this in the meantime? ideally cmake would provide an option to add an include file to the generated _automoc file, right?

Answer (score 2):

The correct variable to set is called [CMAKE_AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS). It is used to initialize the `AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS` property of a target, i.e.:

```
set (CMAKE_AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS "-bstdafx.h" "-fstdafx.h")
```

Also note that this will only make the Qt MOC compiler add the given includes to each generated `moc_xxx.cpp` file. The overall `project_automoc.cpp` will not be affected.

Comment: But I need to affect `project_automoc.cpp` :(. because project count not compile this file without precompiled headers.

Comment: Looking at the CMake source code it seems that the generation of the `project_automoc.cpp` is hard coded and is not configurable.

Comment: @DMitry, my current workaround is to just disable automoc for projects that use precompiled headers, in CMAKE- `set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC FALSE)` and moc the files using `QT5_WRAP_CPP(MOC_SOURCES ${MOC_FILES})`. Then for every moc file in MOC_SOURCES `foreach(src_file ${moc_SRCS})  set_source_files_properties(${src_file} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/YuStableHeaders.h /FIStableHeaders.h") endforeach()`

Comment: @Pencheff, you may post it as an answer. Just one more question (I cannot check it by myself now): is it safe to pass non-qt headers to `QT5_WRAP_CPP`? Or it is prefferable to check each file for `Q_OBJECT` macro (seems slow)?

Comment: @Dmitry, yes its safe to pass any (header) files to QT5_WRAP_CPP, even non-existing files, and nothing will fail, project still compiles and runs fine.

Comment: You don't need to pass both -b and -f, this leads to two #include statements. A single -bstdafx.h is enough (tested with Qt 5.6 and 5.8).

Answer (score 0):

AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS doesn't affect the project_automoc.cpp file. It contains options passed to moc to create "moc_widget_fps.cpp" and "moc_widget_sysevents.cpp". Those should contain your pch includes.

Comment: What I see in my project when I turn on the AUTOMOC ON is, for every file.h that has a class with Q_OBJECT in, I get a corresponding moc_file.cpp in the build directory. These files are not added to my (visual studio) project, instead I get a single project_automoc.cpp file that includes all the moc'ed cpp files in it. Since my project uses precompiled headers, this file should include stdafx.h. If I manually add /FIstdafx.h to that file in VS, it compiles fine

Comment: Verify that the moc command line contains the appropriate -b and -f options when creating moc_file.cpp.

Comment: @steveire not sure how will it help to add the -b/-f option if that doesn't add anything to the `_automoc` file, and compiler complains about this file only, not about `moc_` files?

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps more elegant way is to disable precompiled headers for the `mocs_...` file. This allows you to keep `AUTOMOC`:

```
append_to_source_file_property(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/<PROJECT_NAME_HERE>_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp
  COMPILE_FLAGS " /Y- ")
```

Alternatively if you can/are willing to change the name and contents of the precompiled header file, you can add this to it:

```
#ifdef HACK_FOR_TRICKING_MOC_INTO_INCLUDING_ME_IN_THE_MOCS_FILE_DO_NOT_DEFINE
Q_OBJECT
#endif
```

This will trick cmake into including it in the `mocs_...` file. You then need it to be at the top which requires a name change, files are sorted numbers first, then uppercase, then lowercase, so e.g. `1_precompiled.h` should do the trick.